# Remove deleted component from vue-loader cache

Tags: vue.js, caching, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I created a component and used it in my nuxt app. When my app is runned I've delete it and nuxt return me error message:

[image]

How I can solve error with removed component in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a file "test.vue" in the pages directory. Ie. /pages/test.vue

It would appear that page is trying to load your deleted component. I guess it has an:

`import Unauth from "@/component/Unauth"`

Delete that line and "Unauth" from the components section.